Cross-sectional data in a DiD Design?
I am conducting a difference-in-differences Design (in R), however, not in the classical sense as I have two groups that were treated at the same time, but no control group. My groups are individuals working in a "More-export oriented sector" and individuals working in a "Less-export oriented sector" (Variable exp_sector).
I am interested in the difference of the average treatment effect between both groups (and not the ATE). I am measuring how support for independence changes pre- and post-treatment for both groups (Variable: indep). The problem is that I do not have panel or longitudinal data but merely cross-sectional data for different time periods and different individuals. To circumvent this problem, I created a pseudo-panel based on certain sociodemographic variables and the sector of the individuals.
First, an overview of both datasets:
head(dt17_slct)
  ESTU PROV       date year_month sex age_group                  exp_sector             exp_sector_fact
5 3191    8 2017-10-02    2017-10   2     70-74 More export-oriented sector More export-oriented sector
6 3191    8 2017-10-02    2017-10   2       80+ More export-oriented sector More export-oriented sector
7 3191    8 2017-10-02    2017-10   2     45-49 Less export-oriented sector Less export-oriented sector
8 3191    8 2017-10-02    2017-10   1     45-49 More export-oriented sector More export-oriented sector
9 3191    8 2017-10-02    2017-10   1     60-64 Less export-oriented sector Less export-oriented sector
                   sector_all education indep ideology identity income     work_sit_fact indep_2 pol_know_index
5 More export-oriented sector         1    NA       NA        1      5           Retired      NA              4
6 More export-oriented sector         1     1        6        3     NA           Retired       1              4
7 Less export-oriented sector         5    NA       NA        3     NA Currently working      NA              0
8 More export-oriented sector         4     0       10        3      9 Currently working       0              5
9 Less export-oriented sector         1     0       10        1     NA           Retired       0              5
  good_pol_know
5             0
6             0
7             0
8             0
9             0

head(ds17_slct)
  ESTU PROV       date year_month sex age_group                  exp_sector             exp_sector_fact
1 3187    8 2017-09-01    2017-09   2     40-44 Less export-oriented sector Less export-oriented sector
2 3187    8 2017-09-01    2017-09   2     35-39 Less export-oriented sector Less export-oriented sector
3 3187    8 2017-09-01    2017-09   1     55-59 More export-oriented sector More export-oriented sector
4 3187    8 2017-09-01    2017-09   1     70-74 More export-oriented sector More export-oriented sector
5 3187    8 2017-09-01    2017-09   2     75-79 More export-oriented sector More export-oriented sector
6 3187    8 2017-09-01    2017-09   1     45-49 More export-oriented sector More export-oriented sector
                   sector_all education indep ideology identity income     work_sit_fact
1 Less export-oriented sector         5     1        4        5      5 Currently working
2 Less export-oriented sector         5     0        2       NA     NA Currently working
3 More export-oriented sector         4     0        5        3      7 Currently working
4 More export-oriented sector         5     1        4        5     NA           Retired
5 More export-oriented sector         4    NA       NA        4      2           Retired
6 More export-oriented sector         4     1        3        4      7 Currently working

Here is my code for conducting the pseudo-panel:
dt17_slct <- dt17_slct %>%   filter(!is.na(sex), !is.na(education), 
              !is.na(age_group), !is.na(exp_sector))

ds17_slct <- ds17_slct %>%   filter(!is.na(sex), !is.na(education), 
              !is.na(age_group), !is.na(exp_sector))

combs <- expand.grid(sex = unique(dt17_slct$sex), 
                 education = unique(dt17_slct$education), 
                     age_group = unique(dt17_slct$age_group), 
                 exp_sector = unique(dt17_slct$exp_sector))

combs <- combs %>%   dplyr::mutate(id1 = row_number())

## For dt17_slct

dt17_slct <- dt17_slct |>  left_join(combs, by =c("sex", "age_group", 
                                      "education", "exp_sector"))

t10_17 <- dt17_slct |>  group_by(sex, age_group, education, 
              exp_sector) |>    dplyr::mutate(resp_id = row_number())

t10_17$ID <- paste(t10_17$id1, t10_17$resp_id, sep = "_")

## For ds17 
ds17_slct <- ds17_slct |>  left_join(combs, by =c("sex", "age_group", 
                             "education", "exp_sector"))

t09_17 <- ds17_slct |>  group_by(sex, age_group, education, 
           exp_sector) |>    dplyr::mutate(resp_id = row_number())

t09_17$ID <- paste(t09_17$id1, t09_17$resp_id, sep = "_")

result2 <- bind_rows(t09_17, t10_17)

t3 <- result2|>  group_by(ID) |> dplyr::mutate(count = n()) |>  
     filter(count > 1) |>    arrange(ID) |>    
     select(ID, everything()) |>  
     select(-id1, -resp_id, -count, -sector_all)

## Balanced panel-data
t3 <- t3 |> 
  filter(!is.na(indep))

However, I am left with 39 observations. These are not enough observations to conduct a Linear Probability Model (LPM). I was thinking that maybe I could use both cross-sectional data in my analysis, to avoid the problem of the small sample created by the pseudo-panel. Separately, they have 222 and 236 observations (removing the missings for my dependent variable).
What assumptions, implications, and challenges does this pose for my difference-in-differences design?
Alternatively, is it still feasible to use the pseudo-panel despite the small sample size?
